# problem disassembling a wooden recorder

Tags: recorder

I recently purchased a new Aura wooden recorder. The joint has a cork band. I greased it carefully with what I thought was plenty of the enclosed lubricant before putting it together. But I find I cannot get it apart again. We are in an especially humid weather spell right now, so presume it expanded once I took it from its case. My only thought is to leave it as is until drier weather and hope it will loosen again. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to twist it off?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to ask where you bought it, but I'll brainstorm and suggest enclosing it in a large tupperware-type box, with half a cup of uncooked, dry rice to sponge up the humidity in the air in the box.  But I would check it once a day so you don't overdo it.

Comment: If it won't twist, as Jacob recommends, take it to someone who works on wind instruments. Humidity may or may not be the problem.

Comment: I did indeed try to twist it off, no movement. (I am well used to wind instruments, owning several flutes. None has ever stuck to this degree before)  I might try that rice trick, thanks.

Comment: in my experience "plenty" might have been too much. I only apply a very thin film.

Answer (score 2):

**Grease**

- Typically with cork grease, a little can go a long way. Sometimes when there is too much, it becomes sticky and does make it hard to unscrew the parts of a recorder/clarinet/saxophone.

**Cork**

- It is very very common for a new instrument's cork to swell. I personally do not know about the brand Aura, but Buffet R13 Clarinets, for example, take a few weeks to settle in. Students often have a very hard time unscrewing their instrument and tend to press on the keys.

**Weather**

- Humid weather can definitely cause the cork tendons to swell. But, it should not be the cause of you not being able to take apart your instrument. Most likely, it is the pressure of the cork on a new instrument combined with the humidity. Be patient and slowly try screwing it off every day - do not apply more cork grease unless you feel like it is really dry. Wait at least a couple weeks of slow unscrewing before taking it to a repair shop.

**Caution**

- Do not use an excessive amount of force when unscrewing your recorder. Go to your local music store or talk to your warranty provider to make sure that this is normal with this kind of brand.